# Populate observable with data from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a controller from which I send some data to View using ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
string us = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);     
var user = unitOfWork.userRepository.Get().Where(w => w.Login == us).Select(s => new { credentials=s.Name+" "+s.Surname}).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.user = user.credentials.ToString();
return View();
}
```

This data is used to populate this hidden field:

```
@Html.Hidden("user", (object)ViewBag.user, new { data_bind = "value:requestingPerson" })
```

and this is bind to:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.requestingPerson = ko.observable();        
}
```

but its rendered as:

```
<input data-bind="value:requestingPerson" id="user" name="user" type="hidden" value="">
```

without value.
Is there any way to fix it?